# Center two text into AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar

I'm trying to center two text into the Appbar.
The second text is a counter that change dimensions due to the number. If I don’t fix these texts, on every increment, the entire text seems to move and I don't like it!
The results with the code below seems good but if I remove the -100 on the sizedbox.width the result is the pixel overflow error.
Have you got better suggestions to center two text at the center of the appbar? I suppose that with my code, if I run the app into a tablet, the text will not centered!
Waiting for a feedback.
Regards.

```
return AppBar(                                                                              
      elevation: 0.0,                                                                           
      centerTitle: true,                                                                       
      //automaticallyImplyLeading: false,                                                       
      titleSpacing: 0.0,                                                                        
      title: Row(                                                                               
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,                                            
        children: [                                                                             
          SizedBox(                                                                             
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,                                       
            child: Text(                                                                                         
                getTranslated(context, 'total_click:'),                                         
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,                                               
                textAlign: TextAlign.right),                                                     
          ),                                                                                     
          SizedBox(                                                                             
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 - 100,                                       
            child: Text("$appbarcounter",                                                                                              
                textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,                                               
                textAlign: TextAlign.left),                                                      
          ),                                                                                     
        ],                                                                                      
      ),
```

[Picture without -100 pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIpIs.jpg)

Comment: Can you show a image of the output or overflow error anything ?

Comment: See picture updated. This is the versione with SizedBox(                                                                             
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2 ,

Comment: why you are using SizedBox, try removing it.